# Cannot read property 'run' of undefined discord js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

There was a post for this but it didn't seem to fix my problem. I'm writing a simple discord.js program and when I created a new command called forceverify, it gave the error "Cannot read property 'run' of undefined"

[image: error]

main.js:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

let fetch = require('node-fetch');

const prefix = '!'

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Loaded');
})

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'help') {
        client.commands.get('help').execute(message, args, Discord);
    } else if (command === 'verify') {
        client.commands.get('verify').execute(message, args, Discord);
    } else if (command === 'forceverify') {
        client.commands.get('forceverify').run(message, args, Discord);
    }
})

client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const welcomeChannel = client.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'member-log');

    if (!welcomeChannel) {
        console.log('No channel was found');
    }

    welcomeChannel.send(`Welcome!`);

client.login('The token is there');
```

forceverify.js

```
const { DiscordAPIError } = require("discord.js");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const packageData = require("../package.json");

module.exports = {
  name: 'verify',
  description: "Verify yourself to get access to the server",
  execute(message, args, Discord) {
    if (message.member.roles.cache.has('805210755800367104')) {
      const clientUser = client.users.fetch(args[1]);
      let myRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get("805531649131151390");

      fetch(`https://api.sk1er.club/player/${args[0]}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(({ player }) => {
          clientUser.member.setNickname(player.displayname).catch(console.error);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    } else {
      message.channel.reply("You don't have sufficient permissions.");
    }
  }
}
```

Every other command works properly but for some reason, this one simply doesn't work. I tried what the other question said to do (which is add .execute to module.exports or change .execute to .run) neither worked probably because it simply can't find the file (everything was spelled correctly)

Comment: Accidentally forgot to change back from .run to .execute (it still doesn't work) because it's still undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The export from `forceverify.js` has the name `verify` but it should be `forceverify`. So, the `forceverify` command isn't registered and `client.commands.get('forceverify')` returns `undefined`.

```
// commands/forceverify.js

module.exports = {
  name: 'forceverify',
  description: 'Force verify yourself to get access to the server',
  execute(message, args, Discord) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

And you should call the `execute` function when invoking the command.

```
client.commands.get('forceverify').execute(message, args, Discord)
```

You can refactor your code to simplify the command invocation code.

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) {
    return
  }

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/)
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase()

  if (!client.commands.has(command)) {
    return
  }

  client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args, Discord)
})
```